# Selenium Python WebScraping not returning HTML Content

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the HTML content of this website and it seems like every time I try to do it returns some JS and a lot of lot HTML I want.

```py
try:

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
    from selenium import webdriver

    import os

    import lxml.etree
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import json
    from time import sleep

    from fake_useragent import UserAgent
except Exception as e:
    pass


def traverse(soup):
    if soup.name is not None:
        dom_dictionary = {}
        dom_dictionary['name'] = soup.name
        dom_dictionary['children'] = [ traverse(child) for child in soup.children if child.name is not None]
        return dom_dictionary


PATH = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'windowsDriver/chromedriver')

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,executable_path=PATH)

driver.get("https://professional-management-eldercarealliance.icims.com/jobs/search")

html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
sleep(3)
html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
innerHTML = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(innerHTML, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Any help would be great its returning incorrect HTML i am looking for Jobs HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can access the full HTML of the web page with the `page_source` attribute.

```py
import bs4
import selenium.webdriver

browser = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("<url>")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="html.parser")
```